# d3 - problem aligning text with circle center - dominant-baseline not working on Firefox

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to build legend using circle in the following code:

```
    gap_between_circles = 5;
    circle_text_gap = 2;
    circle_r = 7;

    index = 0;

    for(key in colors)
    {
        g.append("circle")
        .attr("cx",width)
        .attr("cy",(circle_r*2 +gap_between_circles)* index)
        .attr("r", circle_r)        
        .style("fill",colors[key]);

        g.append("text")
        .text(key)
        .attr("x", width + circle_r + circle_text_gap)
        .attr("y", (circle_r*2 +gap_between_circles)* index)
        .attr("dominant-baseline","middle");

        index++;
   }
```

It shows up like this on Firefox:

[image]

Notice how the text is not aligned with the center of the circle.
How do I fix this?

Note : the problem doesn't happen on Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that the `dominant-baseline` that you chose works well for lower-case letters, but not for upper-case or numbers.

I created a [pen here](https://codepen.io/joseph4tw/pen/PoqzYwN) to illustrate (and image below).

For the first two items, the alignment uses the `dominant-baseline` of `middle`, but in the third if you use `mathematical` it lines up nicely.

[image]